# Problema con el widget Combobox

Tags: tkinter, combobox

quiero consultar con ustedes sobre un error que está entregando el Widget Combobox "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'", no entiendo por qué emite este error si estoy siguiendo lo que indica la literatura. La rutina es la siguiente:

```
`def frame_dbm(self): # NNo olvidar dar  self.sentinel el valor  False !!!!! Generar un FRame BASE para integrar el Label Frame
        def list1_changed(event):
            value=self.list1.get()
            print(value)

        self.LF2=LabelFrame(self.left_frame,bg="white", text="System's Data")
        self.LF2.grid(column=0,row=1,padx=2,pady=10)
        array=self.GI.view_table_log()
        self.n=StringVar()
        self.list1=ttk.Combobox(self.LF2,textvariable=self.n,values=array,state="readonly").grid(pady=5, row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.list1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",list1_changed())
        `
```

la Variable array se alimenta de información de un módulo externo que lee un archivo .DB el cual tiene el siguiente código:
`import sqlite3 as sqlite
import os

class Gen_info:

```
def __init__(self):
    
    folder=os.getcwd()
    db_folder=(folder+os.sep+"Data_Bases"+os.sep)
    self.db_name=(db_folder+'database.db')
    print(self.db_name)

    self.view_table_log()

def sql_password(self,esp1,esp2):
        query='SELECT * FROM Users_guide WHERE user=? AND password=?'
        parameters=(esp1,esp2)
        self.run_query(query,parameters)
        if self.result.fetchall():
            return True
        else:
            return False
            

def validation(self,data1,data2):
    return len(data1)!=0 and len(data2)!=0


def run_query(self,query,parameters=()):
    with sqlite.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
        self.cursor=conn.cursor()
        self.result=self.cursor.execute(query,parameters)
        conn.commit()
    return self.result

def view_table_log(self):
    query='SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type="table" ORDER BY name'
    self.run_query(query)
    array=list([item[0]for item in self.cursor.fetchall()])
    return array
    `
```

No sé por qué el widget combobox al querer pasar el método "bind" arroja el siguiente error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bind'"

Gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

quiero comentar sobre el error **AttributeError: 'NoneType'**, al usar el comando bind en conjunto con la opción grid `self.list1=ttk.Combobox(self.LF2,textvariable=self.n,values=array,state="readonly").grid(pady=5, row=0, column=0, sticky=W)` el valor ontenido es None por tanto se genera el error citado al inicio del párrafo.
La forma de resolver esto es colocar el método grid en una línea diferente a la que está el método bind:`self.list1.grid(pady=5, row=0, column=0, sticky=W)`.

Créditos : @RandomDavis